# Is an identity relation unique or can there be multiple?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

My question is that suppose a set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$
so, the identity relation can be $R_1 = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)\}$
but can it be $R_2 = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$?

Answer (score 2):

No, the identity relation is reflexive: all elements stand in the identity relation to themselves (and no elements stand in the identity relation to any element other than themselves). So it is $R1$.  It *has* to be $R1$. For any set there is one and only one identity relation.